# Check if string is already HTML escaped (JS)

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code to HTML escape:

```
var __entityMap = {
  "&": "&amp;",
  "<": "&lt;",
  ">": "&gt;",
  '"': '&quot;',
  "'": '&#39;'
};

String.prototype.escapeHTML = function() {
  return String(this).replace(/[&<>"']/g, function(s) {
    return __entityMap[s];
  });
};
```

But my question is, how can I know that I already HTML escaped a string, so that content is not messed up due to multiple calls to escapeHTML() ?

Comment: I'm not sure you *can* know that. What if someone's original input was "&amp;" (e.g., to demonstrate how to write the entity)? Then it would be correct to render that as "&amp;amp;" despite it being seemingly double escaped.

Comment: If your content is messed up due to multiple calls to escapeHTML, then there's something wrong with the logic of your program. Covering that up by allowing for bad program logic is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to compare the actual string (put by user) and the escaped string (put by js), if they are equals, it is already escaped.